# Why is the hexdump of my Unicode text file different from the byte sequence I manually entered?

Tags: unicode, hexdump

Why does the following lead to such a different byte sequence in the hexdump?

```
$ echo -e "\u0f67\u0fb9\u0fa8\u0fb3\u0fba\u0fbc\u0fbb\u0f83\u0f0b" > uni
$ hexdump uni
0000000 bde0 e0a7 b9be bee0 e0a8 b3be bee0 e0ba
0000010 bcbe bee0 e0bb 83be bce0 0a8b
000001c

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Locale is correctly set to: en_US.UTF-8 and the actual unicode output is correct:   ཧྐྵྨླྺྼྻྃ་

Comment: My first guess was for UTF-8. U+0F67 is 0xE0 0xBD 0xA7 in UTF-8. But that output looks like a messed up variant of UTF-8. What does `$ locale` output?

Comment: No, that's definitely the utf-8 encoded version.  The byte order is clumsy, displayed as though it was utf-16le.

Answer (score 1):

My misconception stems from believing that the characters I echoed were utf8, when they are in fact utf16. When [looking up the first character](http://www.charbase.com/0f67-unicode-tibetan-letter-ha), the utf8 is displayed as

```
 e0 bd a7
```

Which should be in big endian. So to change the endianess, hexdump can be run with the -C parameter.